# how i can get index in recursive function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, recursion

```
let array = [1, [2, 3, [4, 5, ["six", "seven", 6666, [8, 9, [10]]]]]]
    //1.find last element
   //2. index way like in **console.log(array[1][2][2][3][2][0]** but should print 
  // [1][2][2][3][2][0] or 1,2,2,3,2,0
```

in this function i find last element now i can't find the 2nd question
(it should be recursive function )

```
  function findLastElement (arr){
       for (let element of arr ){
          if(typeof element === "object"){
             findLastElement(element)
              console.log(element)
          }
       }
  }

findLastElement(array)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to always take the last index, and continue if the the last item is an array as well:

```js
const getLessIndexes = arr => {
  const last = arr.length - 1
  
  return [
    last,
    ...Array.isArray(arr[last]) 
      ? getLessIndexes(arr[last]) 
      : []
  ]
}

const array = [1, [2, 3, [4, 5, ["six", "seven", 6666, [8, 9, [10]]]]]]

const result = getLessIndexes(array)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: sorry if it sound stupid but after return why you are using **[  ]** ?

Comment: Array spread works on arrays or iterables, so if the last value is not an array spread would throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries)

```js
function findLastElement (arr){
  for (let [index, element] of arr.entries() ){
    if(typeof element === "object"){
      findLastElement(element)
      console.log(element)
      console.log(index)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [1, [2, 3, [4, 5, ["six", "seven", 6666, [8, 9, [10]]]]]];

function findLastElement (arr){
  for (let [index, element] of arr.entries() ){
    if(typeof element === "object"){
      findLastElement(element)
      console.log(element)
      console.log(index)
    }
  }
}

console.log( findLastElement(array) )
```